# How to call this default args function more than once?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, ecmascript-6

I have encountered a question where I need to allow default args to be set on a function in JavaScript:

```js
function dfltArgs(func, params) {

  const strFn = func.toString()
  console.log(strFn)
  const args = /\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(strFn)[1].split(',')

  const defaultVal = (arg, val) => typeof arg !== 'undefined' ? arg : val

  return (...dynamicArgs) => {
    const withDefaults = args.map((arg, i) =>
      defaultVal(dynamicArgs[i], params[args[i]]))
    return func(...withDefaults)
  }

}

function add (a, b) { return a + b }
var add_ = dfltArgs(add,{b:9})
console.log(add_(10)) // Should be 19
var add_ = dfltArgs(add_,{b:3})
console.log(add_(10)) // Should now be 13
```

However, I need to be able to call this function more than once and overwrite previously set defaults:

```
var add_ = defaults(add,{b:9})
add_(10) // Should be 19
var add_ = defaultArguments(add_,{b:3})
add_(10) // Should now be 13
```

This does not work in my implementation, because the stringified function on the second call is: `(...dynamicArgs) => {`, etc.

How can I refactor this? Probably need to use `bind` somehow?

Comment: `Function.bind()` does exactly this, create a new function with some parameters and/or the 'this' context bound to fixed values: `var add = function( x, y ) { return x + y; }; var add5 = add.bind( null, 5 );`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: @AndréKool Delete it then.

Comment: Locking. Andre is right.  Could you let us know why you're trying to deface your own post?

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating an Answer, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users should proactively revert such changes. I have done/will do so here. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of your complicated default args thing, why not just use some arrow functions with real default arguments:

```
 var _add = (a, b = 8) => add(a, b);
```

That way you can easily change the bound things:

```
 var add_ = (a = 2, b) => _add(a, b);
 add_() // 10
```