# Access a function which is being used as an argument to another function

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I'm not sure how to explain this problem but I'll do my best. 
Currently, I'm tackling the 'Default Arguments' kata on codewars. This involves creating a function 'defaultArguments', that can take another function as an argument, along with an object with the default values to be used. This function is then set to be equal to a variable which is then called with other arguments. Basically, the idea is to use the default arguments if no arguments are provided with the function call. But, the default arguments are not used when the argument is present. So, the tests provided on this kata are as follows:

```
function add(a,b) { return a+b; }
var add_ = defaultArguments(add,{b:9});
Test.assertEquals(add_(10), 19);
Test.assertEquals(add_(10,5), 15);
var add_ = defaultArguments(add_,{b:3});
Test.assertEquals(add_(10), 13);
```

I've managed to create a piece of code that will correctly function when the function is provided similar to the 'add' function. However, I'm now encountering the below function and my code is failing.

```
var closure_counter = (function accumulator() { var counter = 0; return function (x) { return counter += x; }; })();
```

I think this 'closure_counter' is then passed into the defaultArguments function as before.

However, to use the previous 'add' function as an example, the first stage in my program was to convert the function argument into a string:

```
function_string = func.toString();
```

And then use this string to basically isolate the code that needs to run. In the 'add' example, this would console.log the following:

```
FUNCTION STRING: function add(a,b) { return a+b; }
```

I would then return this along with other information using:

```
let new_function = new Function():
```

And the remainder of my programme would run. The problem seems to be when I encounter the above 'closure_counter' function. When I use the same func.toString() and console.log(), my output is this:

```
FUNCTION STRING: function (x) { return counter += x; }
```

So it basically misses the first part of the function which included the declaration of the variable counter. This is required for the execution of my code.

Basically, is there anyway to either access this variable later on in my code, or alternatively, to pass it into the func.toString() so I can isolate the variables I need?

Thanks and apologies if this is unclear!

Comment: Any solution that involves working with the stringified code of a function is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Just concatenate some strings?

Comment: @pointy its a codewars challenge. It has nothing todo with real world problems.

Comment: @JonasWilms well one thing that's not at all clear is what exactly the "challenge" is.

Comment: @pointy have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745784/how-to-call-this-default-args-function-more-than-once/51745881#51745881

Comment: @ellis could you give me the link of the challenge? I want to give it a try ...

Comment: @JonasWilms thanks for your response. I realise that my post probably isn’t very clear. I’m new to JavaScript and couldn’t really find the right way to describe the problem! The link is here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/default-arguments

Comment: @JonasWilms With regards to your first comment, do you know how I could access the variable to be able to create a string from it?